# Module build failed: Error: dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/libpng/lib/libpng16.16.dylib

Tags: reactjs, homebrew

I get the following error while loading image :

```
Module build failed: Error: dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/libpng/lib/libpng16.16.dylib
```

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I resolved the issue with `brew install libpng` as suggested [here](https://github.com/tcoopman/image-webpack-loader/issues/51).

Answer (score 1):

According to this
https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/3806

I tried this command

```
brew link --overwrite libpng
```

It worked like a charm!!
[image]